# Update Spyder 3.2.6 to 3.2.7

Tags: python, anaconda, upgrade, conda

I have just downloaded/installed Anaconda again after a department store destroyed all my permissions when fixing a power cable and I need to update spyder to 3.2.7

However the updates screen says to not use pip install as it will likely break my installation As aparrently I am using Anaconda/miniconda. Not an option I chose but oh well. Anyway it says to wait until new conda packages are available and update that way.

Searched system for conda and nothing so tried in Anaconda prompt.

conda install -- upgrade spyder

Which should have worked I think.

To no avail.

Please excuse been awhile

Comment: # All requested packages already installed.


(base) C:\Users\anwar> conda update -n base conda
Solving environment: done

Comment: Don't add information in the comments, its confusing. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49228341/edit) them into your question.

Comment: having to upgrade conda first. got error. (base) C:\Users\anwar>block should really be the equivalent of
'block' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Open anacondaprompt

type
    conda upgrade spyder
should ask for conda upgrade first
follow instructions
the retype above command
hey presto up to date. :)